# How to implement jQuery in objective c

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios, objective-c

I intend to get caret position of my webview before the keyboard dismisses. 
There is a jQuery based plugin jCaret can easily do the trick.

```
$(this).caret().start  //this gets the start position of caret
```

It does not work if I use it directly.

```
function getInputSelection(el) {
var start = 0, end = 0;

start = el.caret().start.value;
end =  el.caret().end.value;

returnResult("storeCaretPosition",[start,end,0]); // another external plugin that    
                                                  //calls objective c from java script

}
```

In objective c, I use this to call it.

```
NSString* js = @"getInputSelection(document.getElementById('content'))";
[_changWeiBo stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Where do I do wrong? How to make it work?

P.S: returnResult function works when it is put in the first line of the function getInputSelection, but does not work in the bottom of the function.

Comment: When you call stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString, where are you declaring (evaluating) the script for the function?

Comment: in my dismissKeyboard function which gets called properly before keyboard dismisses.